# Minimal Polynomials for Algebraic Dependence? 

Tags: transcendental-number-theory

Hello all!

I recently had a question concerning algebraic dependence that has thus far gone unanswered from my professors and texts, that I hope I can phrase properly here. When answering, please reference any papers or texts that you may happen to be citing so that I can look them up later! The statement I would like to be true is the following:

Let {$\alpha$,$\beta$} be a set of real numbers that are algebraically dependent over $\mathbb{Q}$. Then $\exists! f \in \mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ of lowest degree such that $f$ is primitive (in the sense of ring theory) and $f(\alpha,\beta) = 0$.

Does anyone know if this statement, or a close cousin perhaps, is true? If it is false, can we add/remove some hypotheses to make it true?

Thank you all in advance for your time and help!

-Richard

Comment: Do you mean that $f$ is of lowest degreee in each variable? If not, we can take  $\alpha = 1$, $\beta$ an irrational algebraic integer of minimal polynomial $p$, and then both  $f(X,Y) = p(Y)$ and $f(X,Y) = p(Y)-p(0)X$ are solutions. 

Comment: Sorry, what does "primitive (in the sense of ring theory)" mean?

Comment: I'm confused. Are you asking whether "Q[X,Y]/I has transcendence degree 1 over Q" implies "I is principal"?

Comment: @Gerry: I presume *primitive* means that there is no nonunit simultaneously dividing all the coefficients.

Comment: Perhaps to meet YBL's objection one wants those two reals to be transcendental?

Comment: Dear YBL, I don't think your second polynomial works.

Comment: You are right, I meant $f(X,Y) = p(Y) - p(0)(X-1)$. One can actually take the sum of the minimal polynomials of two algebraic integers. 

Comment: Thank you very much Dr. Voloch, and thanks to everyone who commented on the question. I apologize for leaving some of the language ambiguous Gerry, I'll work on that in the future. Thanks for the counterexamples YBL, I have a bad tendency to overlook the simpler cases for disproof. Yaakov, I don't think that is my intended question, but I am not well versed in the subject so it may be similar/equivalent. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true if both your numbers are transcendental. It follows from the fact that height one prime ideals of $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ are principal. This can be found in standard algebra textbooks. Otherwise, I believe it's false. There are already counterexamples in the comments.